# How to format a datetime literal in the StrongLoop API Explorer?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

The documentation for the API Explorer is practically non-existent. One of my models requires a date property. The example given in the API Explorer looks like this: '2016-03-27'. How can I add a time to that?

Keep in mind I just need a datetime literal to enter into the API Explorer, not any JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't locate any documentation either. Based on a guess, I tried out some of the `dateString` literals that Date.parse() would parse successfully and found it to be working as expected with loopback. I used the example string formats from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

For example, I used the following dateString for the `created` field in the API Explorer for a `POST \Users` request:

`javascript
{
"email":"username@domain.com",
"password":"pass123",
"created":"Mar 24, 2016 04:00:00 GMT"
}`

The response contained this:

`javascript
"created" : "2016-03-24T04:00:00.000Z"`

I also noticed that, similar to what is described in the link pasted, the Date defaults to local timezone if not explicitly stated.